AppContext.BaseDirectory in C# PowerShell module returns unexpected path
I have a PowerShell module written in C#. I have a "Assets" directory with some files as part of the module. When I publish the module to a local directory, it has structure like this:
|- Assets
|- MyModule.deps.json
|- MyModule.dll
|- MyModule.pdb
|- MyModule.psd1
|- MyModule.psm1

The logic is implemented in MyModule.dll. It uses stuff in Assets directory. I get it's location using System.AppContext.BaseDirectory. The MyModule.dll is used also by other application (console app, win ui3), where everything works. In Powershell, it seems AppContext.BaseDirectory returns value of "$PSHOME" path, where my Assets directory does not exist.
Any ideas how to fix that? Why only for PowerShell the AppContext.BaseDirectory returns something else than where the dll actually is?

System.AppContext.BaseDirectory is the file path of the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies. So in particular, it's not the file path of the base directory where the executing assembly resides. By coincidence it usually is the same, but don't have to be.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-8.0
Try use something else, for e.g. Assembly.Location property.

Thanks! That on the other hand did not work for me in the console app. I ended up with a code that sniffs for Assets directory in both AppContext.BaseDirectory and Assembly.Location and returns whatever it finds. Now it works for me both from console/GUI apps and PowerShell module. If anybody knows about an easier way that works both from console app and C# PowerShell module, please share.

Here a member of .NET runtime team advices against using Assembly.Location: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/5467   "The most common use cases we have seen is when people call this to get a path to the app's directory. AppContext.BaseDirectory is a better API to do that.".

That's right AppContext.BaseDirectory is the best option to get app's directory, but in this case we aren't looking for the app's directory (powershell.exe is the app, not our dll). So looking for assets in AppContext.BaseDirectory first and, if necessary in Assembly.Location, is the best solution here.
